# c++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::insert

Tags: c++

Program is designed to user input a string such as "TheDogIsHappy" then display that string with a space between the capitalized words. 
Program works fine with only one two words, but when more words are in the string:
Receiving this error when program is run:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' 
what(): basic_string::insert
Don't see any point where the string would exceed its bounds since it only loops up to the strings length, so have no idea why the out of range error is there.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string string1 = "";
    string string2 = "";
    int n;
    double length1;
    cout << "Enter String: " << endl;
    cin >> string1;
    n = 1;
    length1 = string1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= string1.length();i++) { 
        if (isupper(string1[n])) {
        string1.insert(n," ");
        n = n + 1;
        }
        n = n + 1;   
    }
    cout << "String is: ";
    n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= string1.length();i++) { 
        cout << string1[n]; 
        n = n + 1;
        }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Press the enter key to continue ...";
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The program works perfectly for me for the input IamALittleTeapotRoundAndStoutThisIsMyNoseAndThisIsMySnout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `< string1.length()` because indices start at 0, so the value of the actual length is not a valid index in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the `string` at its `length`, you will go one spot out of the range. It is like accessing an array of size 5 at `array[5]`. The final spot would be `array[4]`.